# General tips or flowchart for debugging slow database calls?

Tags: database, debugging, database-design

Does anyone know a good *general* guide to debugging slow databases?

I've been asked to debug a website (not written by me) that is running very slowly and hanging or crashing on database calls (a ZendPHP site with a MySQL backend).

I am happy using SQL, but would never describe myself as as a devops type or a database developer, and I want to know the sensible questions to ask first.

I'm looking for something that suggests possible approaches, e.g.:

- I guess I should start by monitoring *when* the database is slowing down - how do I do that?
- Once I know when it's slowing down, how do I go about debugging those particular database calls?
- Is it possible that other processes running on the server that might be slowing down the database? How do I debug those?

And then general strategies to take in each case.

I hope this question isn't too general. I think such a guide would be very useful for many developers.

Comment: First step: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/929/how-to-dive-into-an-ugly-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step should be finding out what the database is doing when it's slow. The easiest way to do this with MySQL is to use the [slow_query_log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html). Some sensible settings are:

```
log_slow_queries    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

Once this is enabled, you'll see things like:

```
# User@Host: myuser[myuser] @ localhost []  # Query_time: 10.000347  Lock_time: 10.000094 Rows_sent: 2  Rows_examined: 4
SET timestamp=1341519484;
select  *  from (mytab) where (field=value);
```

Once you've identified a query which is running slow, you can run that same query again manually to find out what's going on, but this time prefixed with 'explain':

```
mysql> explain select * from mytab;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytab | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  189 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
```

You can then identify things like missing indexes, whether there's unnecessary requests, etc. Some information about the schema would be useful.

If you also install something like sar, or [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/) (setting the sampling rate low enough by, for instance, editing /etc/init.d/atop to change the interval arg to '60' and then running /etc/init.d/atop restart) you can correlate the behaviour of the server at the time of the requests showing up in slow_query_log to work out whether there are any other system contention issues.

Note that databases like MySQL (or, in fact, most applications which don't use O_DIRECT) will take advantages of IO buffering, meaning that once a particular block of data is accessed once, it'll remain in a buffer until the kernel needs to free up that memory space. This means that running the same query time and time again, if that query *is* particularly inefficient, may not give equal results each time.

If you post some more information about the particular query and the schema we could try to look at it a little more.